# JSON Response Displaying in alert vview?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios5

Am new to iphone development i have a requirement like i need to show the JSON response in alert view  (Eg:i have a login page when i give wrong details am getting a response from server i need to show the response in alert view)
here my code is

```
-(IBAction)signin:(id)sender{

            requestSelect = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://abc....?"]];



            NSString *requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"request_parameter={\"EmailId\":\"%@\",   \"Password\":\"%@\"}",email.text,password.text,nil];

            NSLog(@"requestString in subarea %@",requestString);
            NSMutableData *requestData =[NSMutableData dataWithBytes: [requestString UTF8String] length: [requestString length]];

            [requestSelect setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];

            [requestSelect setHTTPBody: requestData];

            connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:requestSelect delegate:self];



               }

               - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:            (NSURLResponse       *)response{
                receiveddata = [[NSMutableData alloc]init ];
             }
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)aData{
                 [ receiveddata appendData:aData];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

                  jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:receiveddata 
                                               encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            dictServerData = [jsonString JSONValue];

            valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"service_status" ]);


            arr_login= [[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[[[[[dictServerData valueForKey:@"webservice"] valueForKey:@"result"]valueForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"service_status" ]];


          objectForKey:@"webservice"]objectForKey:@"result"]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objectForKey:@"userdetails" ]objectAtIndex:0]);



              NSMutableDictionary *DetailsDict=[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[   [[[[[dictServerData             objectForKey:@"webservice"]objectForKey:@"result"]objectForKey:@"data"]objectAtIndex:0]objec          tForKey:@"userdetails" ]objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"data"];

            NSLog(@"details dict : %@",DetailsDict);



            defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:DetailsDict forKey:@"details"];

            UpdateDetail *updt =[[UpdateDetail alloc]initWithNibName:@"UpdateDetail" bundle:Nil];
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:updt animated:YES];
            [updt release];



}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking ? how to show an alert view with a message ?

Comment: yes,i want to show server response like login error or register successfully.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show an alert view with a message do the following :

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle: @"Your Title" 
                                          message: @"Your message"
                                  delegate: nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

This will open a modal alert view (i.e. No touches are passed trough it until you tap the OK) button.

So just put the JSON response in the message (Convert it to a readable string if needed)

Comment: I dont want show the static response i need to show the respose in alert which i got from server

Comment: Than use the response object you got from the server. Convert it to a string if necessary